# How to use mysql's function replace()

Tags: php, mysql

Execute in CMD is ok, but in php mysql_affected_rows() always return 0;

```
$con=mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'root', '123456');
mysql_select_db('gitsrc',$con);
$result=mysql_query('update articles set title=replace(title, "abc","xyz")');
if($result) {
    echo "success".mysql_affected_rows();
} else {
    echo "fail".mysql_error();
}
```

I use PDO, it's ok, but I've used it on a lot of Web sites. now, i can't use PDO, how to Solve this?

```
$DB = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=3306;dbname=gitsrc;charset=UTF8;','root','123456', array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT=>true));
$DB->query("SET NAMES utf8;");
$result = $DB->query('update articles set title=replace(title, "abc","xyz")');
if($result){
    echo "success";
} else {
    echo "fail";
}
```

Comment: can you show your table data ?

Comment: thanks all, i know why. my data has chinese. must use `mysql_query('set names utf8');`

Comment: it's work, how to close this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use  `set names utf8`

```
mysql_query('set names utf8');
```

beacuse your database is `chinese`

Comment: thanks @unofficial if you want to add more details please edit my answer :)